# How to use forward declaration with boost::msm to avoid circular dependency?

Tags: c++, boost, template-meta-programming, code-separation, boost-msm

I am trying to implement a simple protocol with boost::msm. As packets arrive they are processed and dispatched to the State Machine (SM) to be handled accordingly.

My pkt class (i.e. Pkt1) requires a handle to the fsm that would allow it to call `fsm->process_event(...)` (and of course i would add `#include "myfsm.h"` to the top of the pkt1.h).

So far so good. But what if my state machine (say State1) requires to react to that packet by sending a packet itself? Now I would include the "pkt1.h" header to the top of the "state1.h" so i could create an instance of the Pkt1 and call its send() function.

Well as you might guess this final inclusion leads to a "circular dependency"

The sample code (with the error) can be found : https://wandbox.org/permlink/IlFsUQyLPLrLl2RW (its my first time using wandbox, hope everything is OK)

Note) In the "state1.h" file remove the `#include "pkt1.h"` & `on_entry(..)... Pkt1 pkt; pkt.send();` to make it compilable.

> Questions:

1) How should I resolve this circular dependency?

2) I think the way forward would be to add an implementation file (.cpp) for my Pkt1 class and transfer the `#include "myfsm.h"` to this file, thus breaking the circular dependency. But how can I forward declare the `MyFsm` in the header file?

3) I am new to boost::msm/CRTP and the code is confusing to me. How can State1 get access to `MyFsm` while I have not included the corresponding header to state1.h?? (maybe because `MyFsm` derives from the functor front/back end which its header is included and allows virtual functions to call the corresponding  MyFsm functions!!??)

Many thanks for your time and help in advance.

### Code Included:

- events.h

  ```
  #ifndef EVENTS
  #define EVENTS


  // ----- Events
  struct Event1 {};
  struct Event2 {};

  #endif // EVENTS
  ```
- main.cpp

  ```
  #include <iostream>

  #include "events.h"
  #include "myfsm.h"
  #include "pkt1.h"

  int main()
  {
      MyFsm fsm;
      fsm.start();

      //fsm.process_event(Event1());
      Pkt1 rcvdPkt;
      rcvdPkt.dispatch(&fsm);

      return 0;
  }
  ```
- myfsm.h

  ```
  //MyFsm.h
  #ifndef MYFSM
  #define MYFSM

  #include <iostream>
  #include <boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp>
  #include <boost/msm/front/state_machine_def.hpp>
  #include <boost/msm/front/functor_row.hpp>

  #include "state1.h"
  #include "state2.h"
  #include "events.h"

  namespace msm = boost::msm;
  namespace msmf = boost::msm::front;
  namespace mpl = boost::mpl;


  struct MyFsm_ : msmf::state_machine_def<MyFsm_>
  {
      struct State1_ : State1 {}; // use public inheritance
      struct State2_ : State2 {}; // use public inheritance

     // Set initial state
     typedef State1_ initial_state;

     // Transition table
     struct transition_table:mpl::vector<
           msmf::Row < State1_, Event1, State2_, msmf::none, msmf::none >
     >{};
  };
  // Pick a back-end
  typedef msm::back::state_machine<MyFsm_> MyFsm;


  #endif // MYFSM
  ```
- pkt1.h

  ```
  #ifndef PKT1
  #define PKT1

  #include "myfsm.h"
  #include "events.h"

  class Pkt1
  {
  public:
      Pkt1() {}

      void dispatch(MyFsm *fsm){
          fsm->process_event(Event1());
      }

      void send(){std::cout<<"pkt1 sent out ..."<<std::endl;}

  };

  #endif // PKT1
  ```
- state1.h

  ```
  //State1.h
  #ifndef STATE1
  #define STATE1

  #include <iostream>
  #include <boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp>
  #include <boost/msm/front/state_machine_def.hpp>
  #include <boost/msm/front/functor_row.hpp>

  #include "pkt1.h" //comment this line to resolve the compliation error

  namespace msm = boost::msm;
  namespace msmf = boost::msm::front;
  namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

  struct State1:msmf::state<>
  {
      // Entry action
      template <class Event,class Fsm>
      void on_entry(Event const&, Fsm& ) const {
          std::cout << "State1::on_entry()" << std::endl;
          Pkt1 pkt; pkt.send();//comment this line to resolve the compliation error
      }
      // Exit action
      template <class Event,class Fsm>
      void on_exit(Event const&, Fsm&) const {
          std::cout << "State1::on_exit()" << std::endl;
      }
  };

  #endif // STATE1
  ```
- state2.h

  ```
  //State2.h
  #ifndef STATE2
  #define STATE2

  #include <iostream>
  #include <boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp>
  #include <boost/msm/front/state_machine_def.hpp>
  #include <boost/msm/front/functor_row.hpp>

  namespace msm = boost::msm;
  namespace msmf = boost::msm::front;
  namespace mpl = boost::mpl;
  struct State2:msmf::state<> 
  {
     // Entry action
     template <class Event,class Fsm>
     void on_entry(Event const&, Fsm&) const {
     std::cout << "State2::on_entry()" << std::endl;
     }
     // Exit action
     template <class Event,class Fsm>
     void on_exit(Event const&, Fsm&) const {
          std::cout << "State2::on_exit()" << std::endl;
     }
  };

  #endif // STATE2
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) How should I resolve this circular dependency?
>
> 2) I think the way forward would be to add an implementation file (.cpp) for my Pkt1 class and transfer the #include "myfsm.h" to this file, thus breaking the circular dependency. But how can I forward declare the MyFsm in the header file?

Correct. In `Pkt1.h` you would forward declare `MyFsm`, but it's just a typedef to some templated boost type. The easiest way here is to duplicate the typedef (or using) while forward-declaring the class you are using as template parameter:

```
#include <boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp>

struct MyFsm_;
using MyFsm = boost::msm::back::state_machine<MyFsm_>;
```

(If you use this part multiple times, you should probably put it into a header to avoid code duplication).

Then move all function implementations into `Pkt1.cpp` while keeping the declarations in the header. This works because (or as long as) all your functions in there only take pointers or references to `MyFsm`, because the compiler doesn't need to know more than "it's a pointer" at that point.

**`Pkt1.h`**:

```
#include <boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp>

struct MyFsm_;
using MyFsm = boost::msm::back::state_machine<MyFsm_>;


class Pkt1
{
public:
    Pkt1() {}

    void dispatch(MyFsm *fsm);

    void send();
};
```

**`Pkt1.cpp`**:

```
#include "pkt1.h"

#include "myfsm.h"
#include "events.h"

#include <iostream>

void Pkt1::dispatch(MyFsm *fsm)
{
    fsm->process_event(Event1());
}

void Pkt1::send()
{
    std::cout<<"pkt1 sent out ..."<<std::endl;
}
```

Demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/5zMsbolOMPN0biaY

> 3) I am new to boost::msm/CRTP and the code is confusing to me. How can State1 get access to MyFsm while I have not included the corresponding header to state1.h?? (maybe because MyFsm derives from the functor front/back end which its header is included and allows virtual functions to call the corresponding MyFsm functions!!??)

The key here is that `on_entry` and `on_exit` are *template* functions. The code for them is only generated when they are *used* - such as within the FSM implementation (which is inside boost, we can't see it here). That is why they must be in the header: The full function bodies must be visible to the compiler when it *instantiates* (i.e. generates code for an instance of) the function templates. At that point, the template argument `Fsm` is substituted for `MyFsm` (and one of your events for `Event`) so everything is known and works out.

I would recommend reading up on Translation Units and how C/C++ compilers generate code (i.e. what happens with your `.h` and `.cpp` files). Once you understand that, a lot of things should fall into place.

Comment: I had tried your suggestion, but it does not compile. You can find the code: (https://wandbox.org/permlink/TEhccGVJd6ApuKMn )  Thanks for your hint on the 3rd point.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I missed that `MyFsm` is just a typedef. [See here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KcpKxbU0horqDhmV) - I also edited my answer. Note that you also have to add the `MyPkt1.cpp` to the compiler options or it won't be compiled!

Comment: Please correct your post, so I can mark it as solved. Thanks a lot for your help. One final question: Why should I add the .cpp file to the compiler options, and what does this do/achieve?

Comment: So that the compiler creates an object file for each `.cpp` (i.e. each translation unit). The linker then links all of them into an executable (or library). Wandbox automatically adds your `main.cpp` to the options, any others you must add yourself. I won't go more in-depth here because this is exactly the topic I would suggest you read up on, I cannot possibly cover it in sufficient depth here.